# What is the dominant factor for evaluating performance for TTS & ASR?

Tags: performance, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

We know that CPU speed ("MFLOPS") alone is not the only factor that determines the performance of an Android device.

Other factors include the I/O subsystem, memory speed and, of course, the software that drives this hardware.

But in the case of evaluating various phones in terms of [TTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis) and [ASR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition) performance (e.g. minimal delay from the moment you say a word, until it is recognized, given the **default built-in** engine), can we say that MFLOPS is the dominant factor?

In other words, do you happen to know whether **TTS & ASR** involve mostly CPU cycles with relatively little memory and I/O transfers? Or is it the opposite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect TTS and ASR to be very memory-intensive as they process input (which needs to be stored and transformed) and generate output.  So slow memory would probably be a limiting factor with a fast CPU.  There should also be a little I/O -- loading voice samples for comparison and playback -- but I would not expect it to be as much of an issue.  I can't get any more specific since I don't know how the default engine works (I suspect few people outside Google do).

You might get a better answer on StackOverflow, since this is more of a question about the specifics of an algorithm and not really about Android use.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your answer. It's a good idea to post this question on StackOverflow.